# Not able to compile library extend from mllib

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I am working on a ml project using apache spark and maven. I create two library for the project - one called "rmml" which extends Spark mllib library by adding a new FactorizationMachine Algorithm to "org.apache.spark.mllib.regression" and the other library called "dataprocess" uses this new algorithm I added.

In Intellij on my laptop, I am able to call and run the FM algorithm fine in "dataprocess", and I am able to compile "rmml", however I hit an error when try to compile "dataprocess" library with "error: object FactorizationMachine is not a member of package "org.apache.spark.mllib.regression". I am not a java developer, so I am having a hard time figure this out. Any help would be great, thanks!

[image]

This pom of "dataprocess" library that imports "rmml"

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.something</groupId>
        <artifactId>rmml</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is pom of "rmml" project

```
<groupId>com.something</groupId>
<artifactId>rmml</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

And here is class path and file path of "rmml" project

[image]

Comment: Did you already [published **rmml** to the local repository](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-your-project-into-maven-local-repository/) ?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez You are right. This is what I missed. I only manually copied rmml's jar to .m2, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

As Luis suggested "need to publish rmml to the local repository"